Where does MyApp.styles.css come from in Blazor
I see that there is a CSS file MyApp.styles.blazor, but I can't find out where it's coming from -- obbiously it's generated somehow.
What is it supposed to do? Seems to be completely useless because it's messing up default Bootstrap.

This is an automatically generated CSS file that contains all isolated CSS from your Blazor controls.
So you probably have nested CSS files (*.razor.css) below some of your controls that are interfering:

The CSS in these files is isolated during compilation to that specific control, so they only apply to that control, even if you use very generic selectors.
So, for example, if you have the following CSS in Index.razor.css:
h1 {
   color: brown;
}

It will be compiled to this:
h1[b-3xxtam6d07] {
    color: brown;
}

While the control itself in the HTML will look like this:
<h1 b-3xxtam6d07>

For more details, see this documentation: CSS Isolation

AHA! That's it, it's Whatever.razor.css then VisualStudio hides it underneath the icon for the .razor file.

Kindly read this article about CSS styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/ui/css-styles
You will need to search for `Stylesheet tags in the XML looking like:
<StyleSheet Resource="folder/MyApp.styles.css" Assembly="GetType().Assembly"></StyleSheet>

of course, the path may be different for you.
